# $addfield in spesific condiiton MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this data when get by aggregation

```
    [{_id: 1,
      name:'Abraham',
      class:'V',
      question_answered:[{
      id:'quest1',
      answer:'A',
      score:10,
      question:{
        soal:'apa judul lagu?',
        correct_answer:'A',
        type_question:'Essay'
       }
      },
      {
      id:'quest2'
      answer:'C',
      score:null,
      question:{
        soal:'apa judul lagu B?',
        correct_answer:'B',
        type_question:'Essay'
       }
      },
      {
      id:'quest3'
      answer:'C',
      score:10,
      question:{
        soal:'apa judul lagu C?',
        correct_answer:'C',
        type_question:'essay_pg'
       }
      },
      ]
     }
    ]
```

Now i want to addfield with condition
addfield with name
formated_status_evaluation_essay and formated_status_evaluation_essay_option,

with condition:

```
IF(question_answer.question.type_question === 'Essay' && score !== null)
 formated_status_evaluation_essay = 'already scoring'
Elseif(question_answer.question.type_question === 'Essay' && score === null)
 formated_status_evaluation_essay = 'haven't scoring'
Elseif(question_answer.question.type_question === 'Essay' is not exists
 formated_status_evaluation_essay = 'No essay question'
```

formated_status_evaluation_essay_option is have same condition with evaluation_essay

Soo expected output would be like

```
[{_id: 1,
  name:'Abraham',
  class:'V',
  question_answered:[.........]
  formated_status_evaluation_essay:'havent Scoring',
 formated_status_evaluation_essay_option:'Already Scoring'
 }
]
```

How to write a correct addfield with condition in mongodb to make an output like that?
thanks before i've tried soo many ways but still got no answer.

i tried this but seems i put a wrong syntax

```
      { 
        '$addFields': { 
          'formated_status_evaluation_essay': { 
               '$cond': [ 
                   {
                    '$and': [ 
                      {'$$question_answer.question.type_soal ': 
                      'essay'},
                      {'$$question_answer.nilai':{$ne:null}},
                      ]    
                    },
                   'already scoring', 
                   'havent scoring' 
               ] 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: In the example you have three `question_answered`, but only one condition...Do you want to add these fields to the doc if the condition matches at least one of the  `question_answered`, or, do you want to add it to each one of the `question_answered` according to its own properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      formated_status_evaluation_essay: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $and: [
              {
                $in: [
                  "Essay",
                  "$question_answered.question.type_question"
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  "$question_answered.score",
                  null
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "already scoring",
          "havent scoring"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I6JrUuhIgLE)